# How can I install pyobjc for python3?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyautogui

How can I install pyobjc for python3? Is it even possible to use pyobjc with python3? I want to use pyautogui and it requires pyobjc and pyobjc-core. I am using macOS High Sierra.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best solution (but it worked for me)...

I did:

`xcode-select --install`

`pip3 install pyobjc-core`

`pip3 install pyobjc-framework-Cocoa`

`pip3 install pyobjc-framework-Quartz`

In this specific order